# How to handle authentication count to be compliant with CQRS pattern?

Tags: authentication, cqrs

I need to count improper authentication attempts to some accounts in my application. If some certain value is reached i need to block the account. In my understanding of CQS/CQRS, an authentication request is kind of query. Queries should not modify any data on the server side in my opinion. To solve such a problem i should update some attribute in the database while handling the query and this would be violation of CQRS principles i guess. What should i do?? Is an authentication a command in my case (remember commands, cannot return any value so how can i know that authentication is correct for example)?? Maybe i should publish some event after unsuccessful authentication?? How can i solve such a problem? Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Queries should not modify domain state.

I'm not aware of a general prohibition on a command returning data (strictly interpreted, that constraint would preclude any sort of acknowledgement of a command).

The "S" in CQRS is often interpreted too strictly in my experience: any write model (at least any write model which retains the right to decide that a command is inapplicable based on the results of previous commands) carries with it a read model (if event sourcing, that read model is typically going to be a snapshot derived from the write model, but the principle holds).  If there's a query which can be effectively answered from that read model, there's not necessarily any gain from having a different read model handle the query (the best reason to do that separation in that scenario is if there'd be enough query volume that handling "query commands" degrades write performance).

So I'd advise modeling authentication as a command (it almost certainly changes the state of the system) and returning whatever auth status info is relevant/available from an auth as a response to the command.